# Combine two byte arrays of variable length through bit shifting

Tags: c#, arrays, bit-shift

I have two byte arrays, they have variable length but always add up to 8 bytes. These need to be combined into a long. I can do this with creating a byte array and copying the required data. But I was thinking that this should also be possible through bit-shifting. I've been trying this (simplified with just one length):

```
        var bytes1 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        var bytes2 = new byte[] { 8 };
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* b1 = bytes1)
            {
                fixed (byte* b2 = bytes2)
                {
                    ulong* bl1 = (ulong*)b1;
                    ulong v = (*bl1<< 8)  | (*b2);

                    var bytes = bytes1.Concat(bytes2).ToArray();

                    // These two are different:
                    Console.WriteLine(v); 
                    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0));
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm aware that `Concat` works, but I'd like to this to work too.

Comment: Why not check how [ToUInt64](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,681f6fa6df99de55) does it? It uses bit shifting as well but *unrolls* the loop because this method *is* performance critical

Comment: On the other hand, the same method in [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/BitConverter.cs) obviously cheats and uses Span tricks to just read the 8 bytes as a long

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos note, that his arrays do not meet the minimum length requirement (less than 8 bytes).

Comment: When making `long` manually, check *ending* `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` (you may want to `Reverse()` the array)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `(ulong*)b1` is an out of bounds read because the array has length 7 and `sizeof(ulong) == 8`. The next read is also broken in that way. Alignment is also a problem. I don't see a way to rescue that approach. You could read 4 bytes, then 2 bytes, then 1 byte if you really are looking for performance.

I'd loop over the arrays and shift in each byte:

```
ulong result = 0;

void MergeArray(byte[] bytes) {
 foreach (var b in bytes) {
  result = result << 8 | (ulong)b;
 }
}

MergeArray(bytes1);
MergeArray(bytes2);
```

Using a local function for code sharing.

You can improve performance by taking 4 bytes as the first chunk if the array length supports a read of that size. Then, fetch 2, then fetch 1. That way there is not even a loop and the number of operations is minimized.

Whether this is good or not depends on your need for performance which must be traded off with code legibility.

Comment: Worth checking how [BitConverter in the Full Framework does it](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,681f6fa6df99de55). Pointer arithmetic and shifting. The same method in .NET Core though [cheats](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/3b24c535852d19274362ad3dbc75e932b7d41766/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/BitConverter.cs#L331) by using the same internal methods that Span uses.

Comment: @usr Yes, I've been thinking about that too. I like this solution though, I'll try it out!

Comment: @TheCookiesDog actually, what's your goal? Performance or just learning?

Comment: A little of both, but mostly I'd like to learn how to get it to work :)